# TableView not displaying data in ViewController: Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

Everything was working fine when I had it in an entire TableViewController, but because I need to have a dropdown menu I switched over to a basic ViewController to have more flexibility. Haven't been able to display the data since.

I think I have all my bases covered. It is a tableView inside a viewController. Delegate and dataSource are set from the tableView to my viewController. The cell identifier is correctly set to "cell". The data is being pulled and can confirm it is in the collectionsAndArrays object.

Any help would be great, thanks.

**edit: added self.collectionTableView!.reloadData() and still not working**

```
import UIKit

class ImagesTabViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var collectionInfo: NSArray = DataManager.getUserCollections()
var items: NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet weak var collectionTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    APIManager().getData() { completed in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if completed {


                self.items = NSMutableArray(array: self.collectionInfo)


            } else {
                //do something else
            }
        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    var numberOfCollections: Int = self.items.count

    return numberOfCollections

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var collectionsAndArrays = PSCollection()
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")


    // Configure the cell...

    collectionsAndArrays = self.items[indexPath.row] as! PSCollection
    cell.textLabel!.text = collectionsAndArrays.name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = collectionsAndArrays.created_at


    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: In APIManager().getData(), after you set self.items, you should call, self.tableView.reloadData() in order the refresh the tableview with the downloaded elements.

Comment: I tried that, it won't let me call that method from tableView for some reason @DánielNagy

Comment: I see, because you named your tableview to collectionTableView, so call: self.collectionTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Was able to call the method, still not working though. :( @DánielNagy

Comment: Did you put that method after you set self.items?

Comment: Yes, -  self.items = NSMutableArray(array: self.collectionInfo)
                    self.collectionTableView!.reloadData()

Comment: are you sure that the code is executed? There is a possibility for the bool completed to be false.

Comment: Yes: Printing description of completed:
true

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource in the interface builder?

Comment: Added a picture to the post so you can see.

Comment: Did you change the class of the controller with the table view to your custom class?

Comment: Yes. The controller is connected to the custom class.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your constraints aren't set up properly, and the table view has zero size, or is off screen somehow.

Comment: If you put a debugger breakpoint at numberOfSectionsInTableView, is it being called? Also, in cellForRowAtIndexPath function, you should be doing this:     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it is being called. Although I put in a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and that is not being called. Also there are no values for anything when it does stop at numberOfSectionsInTableView.

Comment: Hmmm, that implies that numberOfCollections is zero. Can you put a breakpoint in numberOfRowsInSection, and inspect the value?

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel It was at zero. I'm making progress through it. I added self.collectionInfo = DataManager.getUserCollections() inside the closure and it seems to be pulling the data now. Now I'm getting: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.. looking to see where this may be now.

Comment: FINALLY. It works for cell.textLabel!.text = collectionsAndArrays.name but when I call .created_at I am getting the Optional error...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


APIManager().getData() { completed in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if completed {


            self.items = NSMutableArray(array: self.collectionInfo)
            self.collectionTableView.reloadData()


        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}